# Virtual function binding

Tags: c++

Hello guys have a question about virtual function binding do not know if there is such a thing so i want to ask about this .
[image]

So i have a Game State machine. GameState class is a main class for all state entities , GameStateFirstPhase is a class for entity only for those other 3 classes (StartUp,SelectServer,ConnectServer).

So what do i want to do is to split a draw function and draw all entity of those 3 classes inside a GameStateFirstPhase class, and those 3 classes have their own draw function for only specific things that are for that class, like GameStateSelectServer class would have to draw a UI Select server panel + entity of all classes which is GameStateFirstPhase class.

This is how I want to bind CurrentState draw function with a GameStateFirstPhase Draw function: My game object have a pointer to a CurrentState and call it CurrentState Draw function .

I have tried to call a Entity class draw function inside CurrentState Draw function like this:

```
GameStateFirstPhase::Draw(gfx);
```

but i think that's illegal to do . I hope you get what i am trying to do and it makes sense . I also give image which i explain everything .

The question is if it possible to bind GameStateFirstPhase Draw function with a one of those states Draw functions (StartUp,SelectServer,ConnectSeerver state) bind i mean to get that parent behavior and add a child draw as well

Comment: Great - black on dark blue - very readable

Comment: Sorry for that but font size are big is still not that bad

Comment: "loadgin"? "Ingerit"? "Funtion"?

Comment: Loading Inherit Function sorr , and i have described everything as well

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask or what this image is supposed to represent.

Comment: How to bind a GameStateFirstPhase Draw function with a any of those 3 state(StartUp,SelectServer,ConnectServer)

Comment: It looks like you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I don't understand the "binding" part. As far as I can tell you want to have a virtual function called `Draw` which you override in the derived classes?

Comment: 'bind' is a useful term (and a std::method) within C++.  IMHO it does not apply to polymorphic method invocation.

Comment: What do you mean by CurrentState?

Comment: CurrentState is one of those 3 i have mentioned : GameStateStartup,GameStateSelectServer,GameStateConnectServer

Comment: and bind part is mean i want to get a behavior of FirstPhase class draw function and bind with a CurrentState Draw function addpend to currentstate draw function

Comment: as FirstPhase class is an entity of those 3 classes i want to draw an entity of them Background logo and so on inside a FirstPhase class and rest Draw into each of those classes

Comment: You're not making any sense.

Comment: So you have the overriden function call the base classe's function first?

Comment: yea and then call current class draw function

Comment: i also could say like this i want to get full game screen witch are (background , logo , UI panels ,Buttons ) , but i GameStateFirstPhase draws only a background and logo , everything else is drawn into a one of those 3 states i have mentiones , each of those states have different draw content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...bind i mean to get that parent behavior and add a child draw as well."

If you get around to asking about polymorphism, 'bind' is not the useable term.  Research 'virtual', this is a modifier about a method.

No, the base class (parent) behavior (call it 'foo()') is not involved when a derived foo() is invoked.  The derived foo() is not 'added' to the parent foo() in the sense of a sequence of method invocations.

However, the derived foo() can invoke the base foo(), at any point in its execution.

---

update - add small example base / derived / use of virtual

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


 // base class
 class Foo
 {
 public:
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo() " << std::endl; }

    virtual
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo() " << std::endl; }

    virtual void foo();
 };

 class Bar : public Foo
 {
 public:
    Bar() : Foo()
       { std::cout << "Bar::Bar() " << std::endl; }

    virtual
    ~Bar() { std::cout << "Bar::~Bar() " << std::endl; }

    virtual void foo();
 };

 void Foo::foo()  // virtual method
 {
    std::cout << " -- foo() in Foo " << std::endl;
 }

 void Bar::foo()  // also virtual method
 {
    Foo::foo();
    std::cout << " -- foo() in Bar " << std::endl;
    Foo::foo();
    std::cout << " -- foo() in Bar " << std::endl;
    Foo::foo();
 }


int testFoo(void)  // invoke from main
{
   std::cout << "\nsizeof(Foo): " << sizeof(Foo) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "sizeof(Foo*): " << sizeof(Foo*) << std::endl;

   std::cout << "\n";
   Foo* f = new Foo();   // ctor Foo one time

   std::cout << "\n";
   Bar* b = new Bar();   // ctor Foo + ctor Bar

   std::cout << "\n-----------------\n";
   f->foo();             // foo() in Foo

   std::cout << "\n";
   b->foo();             // foo() in xxx (5 lines)
   std::cout << "\n-----------------";

   // create a polymorphic vector
   std::vector<Foo*> fooVec;

   fooVec.push_back(f);  // Foo* added
   fooVec.push_back(b);  // Bar* added - accepted because "is-a" Foo
   // maybe 100's of different derived methods, added in arbitrary order

   for (auto x : fooVec )  // invoke foo() on ALL elements
   {
      std::cout << "\n";
      x->foo();
   }

   return(0);
}
```

output

```
sizeof(Foo): 8
sizeof(Foo*): 8

Foo::Foo() 

Foo::Foo() 
Bar::Bar() 

----------------- 
 -- foo() in Foo 

 -- foo() in Foo 
 -- foo() in Bar 
 -- foo() in Foo 
 -- foo() in Bar 
 -- foo() in Foo 

-----------------
 -- foo() in Foo 

 -- foo() in Foo 
 -- foo() in Bar 
 -- foo() in Foo 
 -- foo() in Bar 
 -- foo() in Foo
```

Sorry this is so trivial ... my hope is that it helps lead you into research of virtual, pure virtual, etc.

Comment: could you tell this like to noob ? i mean if i get this right so i cannot get parent class draw function behavior and append it to a child class draw function even if i would call GameStateFirstPhase::Draw(gfx); inside a child class ?

Comment: @yahoo5000  No - you can not get "parent class draw function behavior and append it to a child class draw function."  But you can prefix the child class draw method behavior to the base class draw behavior.  All public methods of the base class are available to the derived method.

Comment: I just probably do not know how to ask a question but this sample shows me everything that i need ty